# How to write a left square bracket inside a left curly bracket

Tags: equations

[image: I need to write this]

I need to write this

But I wrote it only with a square bracket

[image]

I can't find how to add a square bracket with my code:

```
\begin{cases}
3x-2=2x,\\
3x-2=-2x,\\
2x \geq 0
\end{cases}
```

I will be glad to any provided help

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Why the biblatex tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below method:

```
\begin{cases}
\left[\begin{aligned}
3x-2=2x,\\
3x-2=-2x,\\
\end{aligned}\right.\\
2x \geq 0
\end{cases}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You don't want `cases` anyway, because it add space for the second column, which you don't have.

Instead, there's `nicematrix`. We need an “almost empty” first column, or the two delimiters would overlap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{NiceArray}{l@{}l}
\hspace*{3pt}&3x-2=2x \\
&3x-2=-2x \\
&2x\ge0
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix\{{1-1}{3-2}.
  \SubMatrix[{1-2}{2-2}.
\end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I was going to post a similar answer, but using `\begin{NiceArray}{\{ \@{\hspace{1em}} l}` insead.